# Preg_match: зашифровать ссылку

Tags: preg_match

Я очень тугой в этом вопросе, мне просто нужно для заполнения формы задать значения для обязательного ввода. С логином, паролем и e-mail я разобрался, теперь мне нужно, чтобы при регистрации люди указывали ссылку на профиль с другого сайта, например, `http://steamcommunity.com/id/12345678/`, мне нужно зашифровать `http://steamcommunity.com/id/`, а всё, что стоит после id, меняется на цифры и буквы. Я попробовал, получилось что-то вроде

```
(!preg_match("http://steamcommunity.com/id/+([a-zA-Z0-9\-])", $_POST['community']))
```

В чём моя ошибка?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам же нужно проверить на допустимые символы в параметре, идущем после `id`?

```
if(!preg_match("/^http:\/\/steamcommunity\.com\/id\/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)\/$/i", $_POST['community'])) {
   echo "err";
}
```